# How to get Average Handle time in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on web app in ASP.NET MVC using Entity Framework. It is a Ticket Log tool for chats. So, if a chat comes in Agent will copy email, and Chat Date and Start time, click on SUBMIT. This will simply create an entry for chat in tool with following fields:

```
Email, ChatStartDateTime, ChatCreatedDateTime
```

So `ChatStartDateTime` will be different then `ChatCreatedDateTime`.

Now the Agent shares support on Chat, and may be he ends the chat after 10 mins. Now, he comes back to the web app and adds his comments for the action taken for chat on web app and clicks a button CHATCOMPLETE.

Clicking this button will update the other field properties like Description field and ChatEndDateTime.

So, now how can I get to know duration in between these fields

- ChatStartDateTime and ChatStartDateTime
- ChatStartDateTime  and ChatEndDateTime

Chat model class:

```
public class Chat
{
    [Key]
    public int ChatId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CustName { get; set; }

    public string Query { get; set; }
    public string Resolution { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime ChatStartDateTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ChatCreateDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ChatEndDateTime { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

ChatLog controller action

```
public ActionResult MyChats()
{
        using (Db db = new Db())
        {
            Chat dto = new Chat();
            
            var uName = User.Identity.Name;

            ViewBag.myTodayTicket = db.Chats.Where(x => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) == DateTime.Today && x.Username == uName).Count();

            return View(db.Chats.Where(x => x.Username == uName).ToArray().ToList());
        }
}
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: It works for me with the following markup @((item.ChatEndDateTime-item.ChatCreateDateTime)), but the duration is showing as 00:00:31.8900000. How can I only show Hour:Min:Sec and not the later part. Any suggestions on this

Comment: Here is how I got it resolved @(string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", item.ChatEndDateTime-item.ChatCreateDateTime)). Now Checking how can I tally all and get average for all Chat Logs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I got it resolved @(string.Format("{0:hh\:mm\:ss}", item.ChatEndDateTime-item.ChatCreateDateTime)). Now Checking how can I tally all and get average for all Chat Logs